# Visual Studio Code Linter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

In the following code if I put space before `{Platform.OS` I will get error
Raw text etc
So how could I make Visual Studio Code check this error before compiling?

```
<StatusBar translucent animated/>{Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 20
            ? <View style={{
                            height: 24,
                            backgroundColor: "#FFF"
                            }}/>
                        : null}
```

Comment: The problem isn't the space, it's the fact that you're rendering `null`. Change the ternary operator and use `{Platform.OS === 'android' && Platform.Version >= 20 && <View />}` (I've omitted your View props).

Comment: @Dan no I understand what you are talking about but I talk about different issue

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4332